# How can I enable two finger scrolling on Synaptic TouchPad in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

I have Dell XPS 17 702X notebook with on board Synaptic TouchPad.

I recently updated Dell licensed Windows 7 to Windows 10 with only issue to get work WiFi driver to  be able to receive other via *Windows Update*.

My notebook is [officially out of warranty and support period](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/xps-l702x/drivers/advanced) and officially Dell doesn't support Windows 10 for my laptop.

But I receive all necessary drivers via *Windows Update*.

My primary OS is Debian and Xorg drivers for Synaptic provides **two finger scroll** to me.

Windows 10 register Synaptic TouchPad as *PS/2 Compatible* (Microsoft [I8042prt Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from 2006 year) and so there are no option to edit gesture preference.

Occasionally I should make tasks on Windows and wander how can I make **two finger scroll** on Windows?

[Synaptic driver download page for TouchPad series](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php) list pack with size of 130 MB. I think that it is **bloatware** and afraid that my system hijacked by vendor ads/spying programs. Am I wrong?

**UPDATE** I check zip content and seems that most space take a `.wav` files. So I assume that installers are not bloated.

I try both (*Windows 10 PS/2 and SMBus Devices v19.0.19.1* and *Windows 10 I2C Devices v19.0.19.1*) setups. Both reported success on installation finish but even after rebooting TouchPad uses old Microsoft signed drivers.

There are note on driver download page:

```
NOTE: Installing a generic driver may result in the loss of 
OEM-customized Synaptics pointing device functionality
```

Seems that *Microsoft generic mouse driver* prevent from properly registering Symantec drivers. Any suggestions here?

Comment: The large filesize of the driver pack may be due in part to localisations (multi-language support) or simply the inclusion of multiple versions of the driver, only one of which your system will actually select to be installed.  Bloatware?  Maybe.  Malware?  I doubt it.

Comment: Ok, I check `.zip` archive from official Synaptic web site and there are a lot of `.wav` files. So really it is not bloated. I try to install but have issues. Seems that *generic Windows driver* block from applying Symantec driver.

Comment: Just install the driver package. If it doesn't switch over to that driver instead, you can manually change it over with the Device Manager, assuming you picked the right driver download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, after 4 hour of digging I manage my issue.

So *first* [official Synaptics drivers](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php) are fine and do not bloatware!

*Second* I find my device TouchPad ID in *Device manager*:

```
ACPI\DLL04B8
```

*Third* I unpack official `.zip` file and search for `ACPI\DLL04B8` string. `WinWDF/x64/SynPD.inf` have match:

```
;%SMB.SynDeviceDesc% = MS_GROUP03_InterTouch_Inst,ACPI\DLL04B8
```

But `;` sign say that my ID is disabled in driver pack. So when I try to install drivers from that pack it is not used as my actual hardware didn't match.

So *fourth* I remove that sign and save file.

But that mean that *Digital Signature* on that file become invalid and Windows 10 x64 will *refuse to install* that driver ((((.

So *fifth* I disable digital signature enforcement for single boot by following instruction on:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-do-i-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-win/a53ec7ca-bdd3-4f39-a3af-3bd92336d248
- http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-in-windows-10-8-7/

Here detailed steps:

> b. Switch over to the “Update & recovery” section.
>
> c. Then click on the Recovery option on the left hand side.
>
> d. Once selected, you will see an advanced startup section appear on the right hand side. You will need to click on the “Restart now” button.
>
> e. Once your Computer has rebooted you will need to choose the Troubleshoot option.
>
> f. Then head into Advanced options.
>
> g. Then Startup Settings.
>
> h. Since we are modifying boot time configuration settings, you will need to restart your computer one last time.
>
> I. Here you will be given a list of startup settings that you can change. The one we are looking for is “Disable driver signature enforcement”. To choose the setting, you will need to press the F7 key.

After booting with *disabled driver signing check* I open *Device Manager* locate TouchPad and enter to *Update Driver Software* menu. Here I click:

- Browser my computer... ==>
- Let me pick... ==>
- *Have disk* button ==>
- Select `WinWDF/x64/SynPD.inf` in File Open dialog ==> Ok ==>
- Select model ==> Next ==> ...
- Reboot

[image]

Now in `Settings ==> Devices ==> Mouse & Touchpad ==> Advanced mouse option` **I have menu for TouchPAD**.

Thanks for watching, good bye!

**UPDATE** I make further investigation.

Synaptics TouchPad require `SynTPEnh.exe` running along with drivers to make two finger scrolling. To control healthy of  `SynTPEnh.exe` there is `SynTPEnhService.exe` Windows service running.

If look to `SynPD.inf` there are present instruction to install this files (to `Program Files`). But I can't find code for registering service so I think there is need to run `setup.exe` which register service.

Comment: How did you find your TouchPad ID in Device Manager?

Comment: `Device Manager` => right click on device => `Properties` => `Details` tab => `Device Id` or `Hardware Id` or similar.

Comment: Looks like I need to do more for my issue since I don't see the device at all.