# Disable driver signature enforcement for single driver installation only?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, digital-signature

I just finished troubleshooting [How can I enable two finger scrolling on Synaptic TouchPad in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1013789/how-can-i-enable-two-finger-scrolling-on-synaptic-touchpad-in-windows-10/) and sites:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-do-i-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-win/a53ec7ca-bdd3-4f39-a3af-3bd92336d248
- http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-in-windows-10-8-7/

say that for disabling **driver signature enforcement** for one time I should:

- Update & recovery ==>
- Then click on the *Recovery* ==>
- *advanced startup section* ==> “Restart now” button.
- Once Computer has rebooted *Troubleshoot* option. ==>
- *Advanced* options ==>
- *Startup Settings* ==>
- you will be given a list of startup settings that you can change. The one we are looking for is **Disable driver signature enforcement**. To choose the setting, you will need to press the F7 key.

I don't trust random articles on Internet and want to know what security implication of that operation and if my Windows 10 x64 still will be safe?

Do I need special steps to perform afterwards? Reboot?

Do my unsigned driver be persisted and wouldn't be replaced with old 2006 year generic PS/2 signed Windows driver?

**NOTE** vendor disable my hardware ID in `.inf` file but its driver still support my TouchPad because driver is generic.

After *uncommenting section for my device ID* `.inf` file *lose sign* and **I have no other option** as install unsigned file but *previously from trusted source with valid signature*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver signature requirement will be *off* until you restart again, so yes, you should restart again after you are successful.

Concerning security: You can leave off the network while you do that install, so nothing else can get to your computer while the driver signing is off, just to be sure. Then the only potential security leak is the driver itself - it is unsigned, meaning it could come from god-knows-whom, and could contain god-knows-what. As a consequence, it could act as a virus or trojan or keylogger or whatever. It's up to you to trust the driver file.

Windows will afterwards not try to replace your driver, if you don't ask it to actively.

Regarding the sequence - I have done that just some days ago, and it works fine that way.